# Click on a button on a row does not select the row as selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a table of test models where I hightlight a selected test with the selectTest function.

When I click now the +/expander button on the tr-tag (row) then the tr-tag wrapping the expander button is not set as selected.

How can I achieve that? -without using a function for the ng-click of the expander button -

```
    <tr ng-repeat-start="person in tests" ng-click='selectTest($index)' ng-class='{selected: $index==selectedRow}'>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
        </td>
        <td>{{person.code}}</td>
        <td>{{person.date}}</td>
        <td>{{person.number}}</td>
        <td>{{person.type}}</td>
    </tr>
<tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
// removed for brevity the rest of the table

  $scope.selectTest = function (row) {
            $scope.selectedRow = row;
        };
```

Comment: Where do you set the `selectedRow` as your chosen row ? (We will need that information)

Comment: In the controller see updated code.

Comment: Try changing the controller body to `$parent.selectedRow = row;`

Comment: @OrelEraki What exactly should I change? When I just replace $scope.selectedRow = row; with your code that does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to use the index for highlighting the row as selected because it may change if you later sort the array or do some dynamic changes to the source array. Instead do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons " ng-click='selectPerson(person)' ng-class='{selected: (selectedPersons.indexOf(person.id) > -1)}'>
...
</tr>

$scope.selectedPersons = [];
$scope.selectPerson = function(person){
    $scope.selectedPersons.push(person.id);
}
```

If you don't have the person ID then use any unique person identifier

If you you want to have a shorter version of the class controller do this:

```
$scope.isSelected = function(person){
    return $scope.selectedPersons.indexOf(person.id) > -1;
}

ng-class='{selected: isSelected(person)}'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my original question.

Comment: You could use my example above to to exactly what you said you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have `ng-repeat-start` but don't have `ng-repeat-end`.

other than that, i'm not sure what else you could have wrong or which version of angular you may be using.

I've created a plnkr with your code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/GtlhULgfaldqdKRUuz8B?p=preview

**CSS**

```
.selected{
  color:Yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('TodoCtrl', 
function ($scope) {
  $scope.tests = [];
  $scope.tests.push({
    code: 1,
    date: '1/1/1',
    number: 1,
    type: 'type 1',
    expanded:false
  });
  $scope.tests.push({
    code: 2,
    date: '2/2/2',
    number: 2,
    type: 'type 2',
    expanded:false
  });

  $scope.selectTest = function(row) {

    $scope.selectedRow = row;
  };
});
```

**html**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat-start="person in tests" ng-click="selectTest($index)" ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedRow}">
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{person.code}}</td>
            <td>{{person.date}}</td>
            <td>{{person.number}}</td>
            <td>{{person.type}}</td>
          </tr>
       <tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="" >
        <td colspan=5>EXPANDED</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes I have a ng-repeat-start and -end. Therefore your sample works. Without the -start/-end my code works like yours. But I need that expansion + the row selection when I click on the row itself and the button. I updated my code.